# accessing to an online service

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, architecture

I am struggling with a technical/functional issue and I would appreciate your views on how to tackle this.

I have a service hosted (web app) and my clients can access to this service either using their own devices (IOS or android) or the devices made available in my premises (as an example let's assume it is a shop in a mall).
Clients may access to the service using either a wifi network we do not control (IP may change) or their 4G connection
The business is asking

1 - **ONLY** give access to the service when the customer is in our premises.

2 - **No sign in** should be asked to the customer to identify the customer while accessing the service

the Question : how to identify the device as being in my shop to allow the access to the service

Any question is more than welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can use geolocation for this purposes.

Just add all the coordinates of point of sales into your backend and ask user to give geo permissions for your app/website.

However, there is drawback, geo could could be easily spoofed and GPS may be not precise enough to meet business requirements (like users will be able to access your app at the parking lot of the mall etc).

Answer (score 1):

1. I like the idea with geolocation, you can track when a user enters/exits specific region.
2. If your mall has permanent Wifi's name then you can check is the user connected to this then you will know he/she is in mall (I use this technique in one of my app).
3. Use beacons, place some beacons in your place then track them (you need background mode permission to track it while app is in background)